# Not able to set the dates on bootstrap calendar from generated dates variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

**Expected behavior**

All I am trying to do is setDates after the ajax call. I have dates array coming from PHP page. So the all dates expected to display as selected dates on bootstrap calendar.

**Actual behaviour**

The list of dates is not displaying as selected/set dates on the bootstrap calendar view. However, it's setting up if I pass only a single date for ex, 23/04/2020 but if I pass dates like 23/04/2020,24/04/2020 in a variable then it's not set up.

**Datepicker version used**

Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.8.0

**Example code**

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "remove_data.php",
data: {ch: ch, dh: dh, sp_rec: sp_rec, cartDate: 1},
success: function(data) {
//console.log(data);

            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

            var myDates = '';
            var temp,temp2;
            for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
                var temp = obj[i];
                var dt = new Date(temp);
                myDates = myDates+" "+dt+",";
                temp2= obj[1];//0=22 1=23
            }
            temp = "2020-04-23";
            //console.log(myDates);


            var dt2 = new Date(temp2);
            var dt1 = new Date(temp);
            //working...but I don't want this solution...
            $('#disc_single_datepicker_1').datepicker('setDates',[dt1,dt2]); //set two dates....

            //Not working...but I want to make work like below....
            $('#disc_single_datepicker_1').datepicker('setDates',[myDates]); //doesn't set any dates.....however it should set all the provided dates......



            display_toastr(datainfo+" record has been removed!","Remove Record",true,"right","info");
            $("#row_"+dh).fadeOut('slow');

        }, error: function() {
            alert("Something went wrong. Please contact admin!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please if anyone can help me on this code as I am trying to fix for so many days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible.

According to [the docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setdates):

> **setDates**
>
> Arguments:
>
> `date[, date[, …]]` (`Date`)
>
> or
>
> `[date[, date[, …]]]` (`Array`)

I'm not sure if the `for` loop you added is the one that you actually work with, but if you do - don't.
Just push the dates into an array, and pass it to `setDates`:

```
var dates = [];
for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
  var dt = new Date(obj[i]);
  dates.push(dt); 
}
$('#disc_single_datepicker_1').datepicker('setDates',dates);
```

Comment: so what you mean here " if you do - don't.
Just push the dates into an array, and pass it to setDates." - so can you please provide an updated answer on my code as don't get it what you are suggesting.

Comment: I have already spend a really good amount of time here and was hopping that actually someone will give me code that, how should I implement this into my code. Please let me know if you need any further details on this.

Comment: thanks for providing code and I'll work on this very soon and will let you know whether it works for me or not.

Comment: bro you are awesome really:) It works really well. I am still learner but I didn't figure it out that I should try push and store it into array.

Comment: do you mind if I ask you again regarding datepicker issue. If you can pass me email or any other information which helps me to contact you. As I am sure I am going to stuck again with some other datepicker related issues. Let me know:)

Comment: @Jimil, I rather you post another question if needed. BTW, there are another 2 questions you asked two days ago, and I think you can delete them, because this answer also answers them. If you still need help with them, let me know. There's another question you asked on the 14th, I'll answer it later.